# Style display none not firing in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function:

```
$(".left_filter_menu").on("click", ".platforms", function() {
  document.getElementById("loaderContainer").style.display = "block";
  console.log(document.getElementById("loaderContainer"));

  areAllPlatformSwitchesChecked();

  document.getElementById("loaderContainer").style.display = "none";
  console.log(document.getElementById("loaderContainer"));
});
```

This should display my loader `div`,  do the function `areAllPlatformSwitchesChecked` and then hide the loader `div`, but it does not show the loader at all. I have added the `console.log` to see why is that, and the output is:

```
(index):731 <div id=​"loaderContainer" style=​"display:​ none;​">​…​</div>​
(index):734 <div id=​"loaderContainer" style=​"display:​ none;​">​…​</div>​
```

When I get rid of the `hide` part, it shows the loader `div`. Any Ideas?

Comment: Take a careful look to your code, you're first setting `.display: block` and then immediately `.display: none`.

Comment: What does `areAllPlatformSwitchesChecked` do? Is it synchronous or async? (And why the weird mix of jQuery and vanilla JS? jQuery has .hide and .show methods.)

Comment: Do you have `#loaderContainer` properties in external css files?

Comment: areAllPlatformSwitchesChecked is not an async function. And it should not matter, the console.log should be first "block", and the second "none". Why does it fire both functions before it loges it out?

Comment: @CBroe it is the same with .hide and .show

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz My css is in a separate file, but the visibility is inline.

Comment: Your debug output indicates both come from the same line in your script: `(index):734` - how is that supposed to make sense?

Comment: @CBroe sorry, wrong pasting, they are different (731 and 734)... I`ll edit

Comment: @MarkoMarjanovic Are you sure the both loggings are showing "none"?

Comment: It's just the console.  Change the logging to `console.log(document.getElementById("loaderContainer").style.display);`  See this... http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/u64k75e3/2/

Comment: I suggest the real problem may be that the display is not updated between setting the loader visible and setting it back to hidden.

Comment: Yeah, the browser will probably optimize your code. Setting a element to `block`, and directly to `none` will in the end result into setting the element to `none`. My guess would be the browser does not even render the item to block level at all, resulting into your 'weird' logging result.

Comment: @JacobvanLingen That's not why it happens.  Think of the console output of the element being by reference, rather than by value.  By the time it's displayed in the console it's been block and then none, so it displays none for both.  You can see this by "decoupling" the object from the browser with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that this is actually your problem, but it often is so it's worth trying.

It looks to me that the element will be set visible, the synchronous method executed and then the element set back to hidden, all before the UI gets a chance to update.  You can force an update of the UI simply by giving the browser a chance to do it, with a `setTimeout()` around the blocking code, like this...

```
$(".left_filter_menu").on("click", ".platforms", function() {

    document.getElementById("loaderContainer").style.display = "block";

    setTimeout(function() {
        areAllPlatformSwitchesChecked();
        document.getElementById("loaderContainer").style.display = "none";
    }, 1);
}
```

Give that a try.  It's a shot in the dark, to be honest, but I've faced it so many times in your situation that it's worth a punt.  Let me know if it works.  If not I'll delete this.

Comment: This actually works :) Although not elegant, but it does the trick. I think it might be an optimization feature in browsers, as even if my areAllPlatformSwitchesChecked function takes longer, the div does not show. 
Your setTimeout trick apparently gives time for redraw. Thanks